# Blue screen of death - graphics card?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

I recently acquired a new computer running Windows 7 with NVidia Quadro FX 3400/4400 graphics card. I noticed something was wrong when I tried playing a game and it went at about 0.1 fps. I went to update the driver on the gpu but just as it was about to finish installing, I got the BSOD. I have gone through the entire process a couple times now. I've done every possible windows update and am about to try to update the driver again. Is there something that I'm missing? I have pictures of the entire process if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed August patch updates.

Form http://thehackernews.com/2014/08/Microsoft-Patch-update-Blue-Screen-of-Death.html?m=1

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/blue-screen-stop-0x50-after-applying-update/6da4d264-02d8-458e-89e2-a78fe68766fd

Microsoft on Friday quietly urged its users to uninstall the most recent round of security updates, after reports emerged that it crippled their computers with the infamous “Blue Screens of Death” (BSoD).

Comment: Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the available drivers for this gpu 
http://www.driverscape.com/download/nvidia-quadro-fx-3400-4400

I have had similar issues before with this card, however that was down to the connection.

May I ask if you built this PC your self or if it was pre built for you?

The BSOD could be caused by various things such as drivers for other other components or similar to my situation with a lose connection.

I would suggest that you open your PC and remove the GPU, then replace and make sure it clicks into place, just incase there is a lose connection which could cause this.

Also, what game(s) are you trying to run with this card, the stats of this card are average so depending on the game depends on the expected performance you will get.

I think with the answers to the above questions this can be resolved fairly quickly.

'Description: NVIDIA Quadro FX 3400/4400 Driver Installer
File Version: 8.3.5
File Size: 2.28M
Supported OS: Windows XP, Windows Vista, **Windows 7**, Windows 8'

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, it was prebuilt for me, I'll try the lose connection thing in a second. I'll also uninstall that security update just in case. As far as the games, they're all really graphically weak so the card should be able to handle them. I could do it all fine on my old computer, which just had Intel graphics that were bad even for Intel. Mostly games from about 10 years ago or a couple from this era that are just easy to run.

Comment: Fair enough, game wise you should be fine then. As I said above, take a look inside the PC and make sure the card is in place correctly. Do a reboot then try to install he newest driver for this card or even let Windows auto update the driver on its own. If it is a new PC, potentially it requires more drivers like motherboard, chipset etc so make sure all these are installed prior to your gpu drivers.

Comment: Awesome, I'll do all that and report back with whether it worked or not in case you're interested

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread, your FX 3400/4400 is not compatible with Windows 7. Maybe the age of the graphics card is the issue?

http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/45415-windows-7-freezes-possible-fix.html